# Numbers in table come with pipes and extra numbers R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a table which inlines some R variables in some cells.

For this I wrote the following markdown:

```
Hello `r s1` and `r p1`

+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Step | Regression        | r      | sd     | p      |
+======+===================+========+========+========+
|  1a  | $Z \sim W | S$    | `r c1` | `r s1` | `r p1` |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1b  | $Z \sim W | X, S$ | `r c2` | `r s2` | `r p2` |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  2a  | $Y \sim Z | S$    | `r c3` | `r s3` | `r p3` |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  2b  | $Y \sim Z | X, S$ | `r c4` | `r s4` | `r p4` |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  3   | $X \sim Y | S$    | `r c4` | `r s5` | `r p5` |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

When I print the variables `s1` and `p1` outside of the table they render correctly.

But inside the table I get the number attached to another number and a pipe. What is going on? Where are those numbers coming from and how do I avoid them?

[image: Output]

Comment: I faced the same issue, but if you can, please use packages like `huxtable` to create tables in RMarkdown

Comment: @MohanGovindasamy how can I instruct R markdown to use huxtable instead of whatever it is using by default?

Comment: You can convert your data frame to huxtable and use it in an R chunk. You can find examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/huxtable/vignettes/huxtable.html))